# Cache not filling error when using mplayer to read from stdin

Tags: linux, io-redirection, mplayer

I have a program that's generating audio and I can't get mplayer to play it. I'm doing

```
./myprogram | mplayer - -cache 1024 -cache-min 30 -noconsolecontrols
```

And I get the message

```
Cache fill: X% (Y bytes)
```

X goes up to the specified `cache-min` value (but not past it) and then it keeps printing the error message:

```
Cache not filling, consider increasing -cache and/or -cache-min!
```

I tried some other values for `cache` and `cache-min` but none of them worked. Of course, there is a possibility that my program is somehow at fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else has this issue: I simply waited a bit longer instead of killing the program immediately, and it worked. Just ignore the scary messages.